# WPF MenuItem and Image share same resource

Tags: wpf, xaml

How would I share an Image or BitmapImage resource between an MenuItem and an Image control.

The MenuItem has the Icon property which expects an Image while the Image has an Source property which expects an String. How would i link them to the same resource if I have the following in my Page.Resources:

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="imgAccept" UriSource="Resources/Images/accept.png" />
```

This can be set as the Source property for the Image:

```
<Image Source={StaticResource imgAccept} />
```

But can't be used for the MenuItem Icon property:

```
<MenuItem Header="New Entity ..." Icon={StaticResource imgAccept} />
```

That shows:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4o62.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<MenuItem Header="New Entity ...">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source={StaticResource imgAccept} />
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```